# Calling worksheet in the form using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check if the value can be found in the lookupvalues sheet. I used userform to create a compare tool and need to check if the data is in the LookUpValues tab. The Form and LookupValues are in the same workbook. When I run my code, I got an error "Subscript is out of range". Below code is for getting the length of the Column A in the LookUpValues.

```
lRowA = Sheets("LookUpValues").Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
```

Can anyone help me identify the issue in my code. How will I call the worksheet in the userform?

The image below shows the structure with userform and the LookUpValues.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a command button or some other event on the userform that will run the code to look at the information on the LookUpValues Sheet?  Also is `lRowA = Sheets("LookUpValues").Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row`the only piece of code you have written ?

Comment: No other event on the userform to look at the LookUpValues sheet. Can you give me an idea on how will I do that?

Comment: Posting a single line of code is probably not going to cut it.

Comment: Fully qualify your Range reference. Something like: `lRowA = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("LookUpValues").Range("A" & ThisWorkBook.Sheets("LookUpValues").Rows.count).End(xlUp).row` Code would be cleaner if you add your Worksheet reference to a variable.

Comment: One way to start on the UserForm issue is calling an event like a `Button_Click()` that will allow you to run the code to look at the information.  All the `lRowA = Sheets("LookUpValues").Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row` does is get the last row of column A.